# Unexpected results when comparing classes in case statement vs an if statment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, equality

So I was writing a module function to convert 'falsey' and 'truthy' values into true and false. To do this I was using a case expression which as far as I can tell is basically just [a big elseif statement that uses the === function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422223/vs-in-ruby) with the === operator [being meant to be used for comparing sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467538/what-does-the-operator-do-in-ruby/4467823#). From the [Ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/NilClass.html) the only difference I can really find between == and === is that === can be overwritten for comparing decedents of classes. I also understand that [everything is a method call in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159149/why-trueclass-true-evaluates-to-true-but-true-trueclass-evaluates) so we can't assume that the equality/subsumption methods are commutative.

When using a case statement to sort by class I would have guessed that the functionality of == and === would be identical but what I found is that when sorting by class they case statement never put my inputs into the correct 'bin'. At that point I switched to using == and it did work so I was wondering why that was the case since I am comparing classes which I assumed would in fact be an "apples to apples" comparison.

```
module FirstTry
  def self.to_boolean(uncertain_value, to_integer: false)
    case uncertain_value.class
    when String
      value = ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(uncertain_value)
      return 1 if to_integer == true && value == true
      return 0 if to_integer == true && value == false
      return boolean_value
    when TrueClass
      return 1 if to_integer == true
      return true
    when FalseClass
      return 0 if to_integer == true
      return false
    when NilClass
      return 0 if to_integer == true
      return false
    end
    # I did not originally include this part of the code in the question
    raise 'Conversion Failed: No rules for converting that type of input into a boolean.'
  end
end

module SecondTry
  def self.to_boolean(uncertain_value, to_integer: false)
    if uncertain_value.class == String
      boolean_value = ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(uncertain_value)
      return 1 if to_integer == true && boolean_value == true
      return 0 if to_integer == true && boolean_value == false
      return boolean_value
    elsif uncertain_value.class == TrueClass
      return 1 if to_integer == true
      return true
    elsif uncertain_value.class == FalseClass
      return 0 if to_integer == true
      return false
    elsif uncertain_value.class == NilClass
      return 0 if to_integer == true
      return false
    end
    # I did not originally include this part of the code in the question
    raise 'Conversion Failed: No rules for converting that type of input into a boolean.'
  end
end
```

Comment: You are asking whether the class of something is a string. Obviously, it isn't. The class of something is a class, not a string.

Comment: BTW, you're doing a lot more work than you need to. `ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast` takes care of strings, `nil`, booleans, ... for you so you don't need all those branches, just `value = ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(uncertain_value)` and the `to_integer` logic should be sufficient.

Comment: `return` is not needed in the last line of each clause (for example, `return false` can, and should be, written simply `false`). Also, instead of, say, `return 0 if to_integer == true; return false`, you can use a *ternary* expression: `to_integer == true ? 0 : false`. If you only care that `to_integer` is truthy, simplify that to `to_integer ? 0 : false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triple equals `===` is called under the hood in a `case` expression in Ruby. We've found it convenient to be able to express something like:

```
case object
when String
  "object is an instance of String!"
when Enumerable
  "wow, object is actually a bunch of objects!"
end
```

This is convenient, of course, unless you're actually holding the class, not an instance of the class. But in your example, you call `#class` on the object in your case expression. Simply drop that call, and your cases will be put in the correct bins. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.class.to_s` for comparison in your case statement

Comment: FYI: The "Community" bot flagged this answer. I'd bet it doesn't understand how terse and clear Ruby is!